# How do I explain this in English?

Tags: sql

```
select S.acnum
from interest S 
where upper(S.descrip) like '%LOGIC%'
    and exists (select fieldnum
                    from interest
                    where acnum = S.acnum 
                        and upper(descrip) not like '%LOGIC%');
```

I need to describe the outer query in English. How do I do that?

Comment: *"i need to describe the outer query in English"* Only the outer query? Then you get half the answer assumming the query would work..

Comment: i assume that this is a home work or a job interview related question? see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to write this as:

```
select i.acnum
from interest i
group by i.acnum
having sum(case when upper(i.descrip) like '%LOGIC%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when upper(i.descrip) not like '%LOGIC%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

This version does not produce duplicate values.  It is saying to get all `acnum` that have at least one record where `descrip` contains `LOGIC` and another that does not contain `LOGIC`.

Comment: *" It is saying to get all acnum that have at least one record where descrip contains LOGIC and another that does not contain LOGIC."* i assume the last sum statement also would have to have `> 0` then..